# NSPredicate usage with NSDictionary with keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i get back all the Water Values from NSDictionary using the NSPredicate? It should return value1 and value2 and ignore value3.

```
 NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"Water", @"value2", @"Water",@"value3", @"Earth" ,nil];
```

Comment: Did you try to run you code at all? If you print `myDictionary`, what's the output? There is unicity of keys... If it's "fixed", do you know the key you want to filter on?

Comment: I haven't tried anything...

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a `NSDictionary`, so you might never see `value2`... And it's unclear what's the logic on filtering. What input do you have? Why use necessary a `NSPredicate`?

Comment: To make a query like "select waterkey values from myDictionary" Thats the purpose instead of using fast enumeration for loop

Comment: There is no really way to do that. You'd have to get only the keys (`allKeys`), apply your `NSPredicate` on that, and create a new dictionary from the kept keys...

Comment: @stefanosn - It's difficult to answer abstract questions. Try to think in terms of "concrete" examples. *"How can i get back all the Water Values..."* is a very vague goal. Get them back as what? An array of strings? A new dictionary? Some other object or collection? Is that the actual dictionary you want to work with? Or, might you have 50 key/value pairs? 5,000? Your best approach may be to not use a dictionary in the first place. But, with only the information you've given, it's impossible to offer a valid answer.